# Flexing Peltier Plate (Physical Question)

Tags: peltier, flexible

I am doing research into Peltier plates for a project, which requires a flexible component. From what I have found, no commercially made flexing Peltier plates seem to exist. My question is, what is the science behind this that inhibits flexing plates? Is it just a matter of the ceramic casing that usually houses standard Peltier plates? Alternatively, do flexing grids of flexible Peltier plates exist?

Comment: tiny Peltier elements exist. If you want the right help and/or more than that you need to share more details of your idea. Such as: Is the curvature fixed? Does it need to move along with something? What something?

Comment: The curvature is not fixed, and not sliding or moving along anything. This "sheet" will need to conform to a curved surface. Think something like wrapping a sheet around a ball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The materials of the individual semiconductor blocks are rigid. I think it would be possible to assemble them on Kapton flex circuits and attach thermally conductive elastomeric pads rather than using the rigid alumina circuits. Performance would probably suffer somewhat, and it could not achieve a very small radius nor could it deform freely like, say, into a hemisphere, as opposed to a cylindrical shape.

[image: http://www.kryothermusa.com/imagez/teceng.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

TECs require an intimately-connected heat sink on either face. If the TEC were allowed to flex, it could not maintain the very low thermal resistance it needs to the heat sink.